# Entity code first zero or one to zero or one relationship

Tags: entity-framework, relationship, code-first

What is the solution to manage Entity code first zero or one to zero or one relationship ?

I would like to have a nav property on the two entities.

I already test with data annotation :

```
public class class1()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Class2 Class2 {get;set;}
}

public class class2()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? Class1Id {get;set;}
    [Required, ForeignKey("Class1Id")]
    public Class1 Class1 {get;set;}
}
```

I always have an error message : "Class1_Class2_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Class2_Class1_Target' in relationship 'Class2_Class1'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'".

I found samples with fluent API but if it's possible I would like to use data annotations. Indeed, for all examples using fluent api there is a navigation property but the int foreign key is deleted from the class :

```
class Class1Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Class1>
{
    public Class1Map()
    {
        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        this.Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.HasRequired(c1 => c1.Class2).WithRequiredPrincipal(c2 => c2.Class1);
    }
}

public class Class1()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Class2 Class2 {get;set;}
}

public class Class2()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
/* Missing Class2Id Property */
    public virtual Class1 Class1 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: a very commonly asked question: *What have you tried so far?*

Comment: To help with your own research, this type of relationship can be termed Optional-to-Optional

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of articles about this, so I suggest you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) article and Google around a little bit further before asking such general questions.